# How can I sync Chrome's bookmarks to Dolphin?

Tags: sync, bookmarks, dolphin-browser

I have Android and iOS devices, so I use Dolphin's browser for the bookmark sync. Is there any way I can get my Chrome bookmarks to sync into my Dolphin bookmarks at least once?

I'm aware of Chrome to Phone, etc. but so far all solutions I see either keep my bookmarks in a separate app (useless for Dolphin Sync) or they only copy them to the default Android browser which I don't use.

My phone's Android 2.3.3, so I can't use Chrome for Android yet.